# How do I check how many rows exists in one column of the same value pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, count, dataset

I have a pandas dataset of about 200k articles containing a column called Category. How do I display all the different types of articles and also count the number of rows a certain category for example "Entertainment" exists in the Category column?

Comment: df['Category'].value_counts()

Comment: Your question is much to broad/unclear for SO, please read again the rules and update your question to improve clarity. Also ensure your question does not already have an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the different `Category` :

```py
df['Category'].unique()
```

And the following to count the number of rows using [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for the category `Entertainment` :

```py
len(df[df['Category'].str.contains('Entertainment')])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), then is possible see unique `Category` values in index and for `count` select values by [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
s = df['Category'].value_counts()

print (s.index.tolist())

print (s.loc['Entertainment'])
```